# How to start syslogd in nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm using an [Nginx](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx) docker container as base image for an application. I'm redirecting Nginx logs to syslog but I'm not sure what is the best way to have the busybox syslogd started. It all works if I start it manually, I just need it to run as a daemon automatically when the container runs.

Seeing that `nginx` is in `init.d` I tried this in my Dockerfile:

`RUN ln -s /bin/busybox syslogd /etc/init.d/syslogd || :`

But `syslogd` still didn't run on start-up. Since the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) says that only one `[CMD]` is allowed I have the following hack:

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
CMD nginx & busybox syslogd -n
```

This works, locally at least, but I'm wondering what is the proper solution. By default the container already symlinks log files to `stdout` and `stderr` but I don't want to use docker's [syslog](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/syslog/) logging driver, because the application will be deployed to [Kubernetes](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) so I need a self-contained solution, that will work in the pod. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your container log to stdout, but collect the logs elsewhere.

One option is to configure Docker itself to [send container logs to syslog](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/syslog/):

```
docker run --log-driver=syslog --log-opt syslog-address=udp://... ... nginx
```

Since the Docker daemon itself is configuring this, the `syslog-address` needs to be something that can be reached from the host.  If you're running syslogd in a separate container, this option needs to point at a published port.

Another option is to use the standard Docker JSON-format logging, but use another tool to forward the logs to somewhere else.  This has the downside of needing an additional tool, but the upside of `docker logs` working unmodified.  [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/docker-logging) is a prominent open-source option.  (Logstash is another, but doesn't seem to directly have a Docker integration.)

Comment: Up-voted because this is probably a good solution. The reason I hadn't used it is because I'll be deploying to Kubernetes. Updated my question, hopefully there are other alternatives still.

Comment: You can also deploy Fluentd as a DaemonSet to ship logs out of Kubernetes.  The Kubernetes documentation [discusses some logging approaches](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/), but they all start from the container writing log content to its own stdout.

Comment: With this approach one can just use `kubectl logs`. Not sure log rotation is taken care of in EKS though, may need to be setup, something to look into.